# How to display the content of a two-dimensional array JSON Object in an HTML table

Tags: javascript, json, grails, groovy, gsp

I'm trying to display the content of a Javascript object into an HMTL/CSS table.
The two dimensional array in Groovy looks like this (It's just a snippet, not the full one) :

`[[null, Pyjamas , Oreillers Traversins, Linge de lit, Protection literie, Surmatelas, Linge de lit , Couettes, Linge de bain], [Pyjamas , null, .3333333333333333, 0.16666666666666666, 0.16, 0.16, null, null, null]]`

One array corresponds to one line in my table.
The Javascript object is created from a groovy controller like this

```
[matrix: matrix as JSON]
```

And here is how I think I have to get the full table in GSP/Javascript and display it (in my console, not in my table)

```
<script>
  var matrix = ${matrix};
  var matrixTab = JSON.stringify(matrix);
  console.log(matrixTab);
</script>
```

What the HMTL table looks like doesn't really matter.
One more thing, I'm using firebug and when i'm trying to catch my array, the console shows me [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K68U6.jpg). Any idea ?

Comment: The code you've shown looks fine, the error you see, does it occur for the table creation or the code snippet above?

Comment: The table creation is not already done so it's not about that, it's about the js snippet I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.stringify()` will output an object as a string but matrix is not a valid JavaScript object here.
`${matrix}` needs to be a string containing your object and then parse it like this:

```
var matrix = '[[null, Pyjamas , Oreillers Traversins, Linge de lit, Protection literie, Surmatelas, Linge de lit , Couettes, Linge de bain], [Pyjamas , null, .3333333333333333, 0.16666666666666666, 0.16, 0.16, null, null, null]]'
// OR
var matrix = ${matrix}
var matrixTab = JSON.parse(matrix);
```

You will be able to go through `matrixTab` and display the table as you need.